# Ambiguous use of Function Error

Tags: swift, swift3, ambiguous

I use the following code,

```
@IBOutlet weak var hashtagableTextView: UITextView!
```

In `viewDidload` method:

```
let hashtagableDelegate = HashtagableTextInputDelegate(textView: hashtagableTextView, userDelegate: self)

hashtagableDelegate.didStartTypingHashtag = { partialHashtag in
    let searchableString = partialHashtag.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
    hashtagableDelegate.showSuggestedHashtags(hashtagDatabase.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchableString.lowercased()) }))
}

hashtagableTextView.delegate = hashtagableDelegate
```

I'm getting error like

> ambiguous use of `contains`

How can i fix?